# Any way to extract the sign of a number in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sign

I have am coding the algorithm of Bolzano in Python. This is my code for now:

```
def Bolzano(fonction, a, b, tol=0.000001):
   while abs(b-a)>tol:
       m=(a+b)/2
       if cmp(fonction(m))==cmp(fonction(a)):
           a=m
       else:
           b=m
   return a, b
```

It works until it encounters cmp, which it doesn't recognise. However I don't see another way to do it, since Python doesn't have a sign function. Is there any other way to extract the sign of a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way to extract the sign of a number?

How about writing your own?

**Implementation**

```
def sign(num):
    return -1 if num < 0 else 1
```

**Example**

```
>>> sign(10)
1
>>> sign(-10)
-1
```

Ohh and [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) is a built-in that requires two parameters (numbers) and simply compares them and checks which of them is larger. You should have used it as follows

```
def Bolzano(fonction, a, b, tol=0.000001):
   while abs(b-a)>tol:
       m=(a+b)/2
       if cmp(fonction(m), fonction(a)) == 0:
           a=m
       else:
           b=m
   return a, b
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use:

```
if cmp(fonction(m),fonction(a)) == 0:
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Shon_Shon's repsonse, this is a version that doesn't raise ZeroDivisionError:

```
int(x/abs(x)) if x != 0 else 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def same_sign(a, b):
    return (a * b) >= 0
```

Examples:

```
>>> same_sign(3, 4)
True

>>> same_sign(-3, 4)
False

>>> same_sign(3, -4)
False

>>> same_sign(-3, -4)
True

>>> same_sign(-3, 0)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a simple solution:
a//abs(a)

Returns 1 if it's higher than 0 and -1 if it's lower, but you run the risk of dividing by 0, so maybe not such a good solution.

Comment: You should either remove your answer or find a solution to your "dividing by 0" problem and update your answer.